# Visual Studio C# using timer to hold down the program for 1 hour

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer

I am a new user and i wish to add a timer to hold down the program for an hour and then continues.

This is the procedure:

1. Issue a command through serialport e.g. high
2. Holds for an hour
3. Issue again the same command 'high'
4. Holds for an hour
5. It repeats until a button is pressed.

How should i implement the timer? Because i tried searching online and found some examples.
I included this in `Form1.cs`:

```
static System.Timers.Timer Timer1;
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(60*60*1000);
     Timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimedEvent);
     Timer1.Enabled = true;
}
private void TimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     serialPort1.Write("high");
}
```

Even though this code helps to repeat the high every hour but it only does the TimedEvent after 60 minutes. I need to write into the serialport first then execute the timer. How do i amend the codes to achieve the result i want?

Edited:
I realised that this code does not work as in the timer did not hold for an hour. Instead place it in form1_load to work.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(10*1000); 
            Timer1.Elapsed += TimedEvent;
        }
```

---

Tried this (below) but the timer didn't work

```
static System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Writetoserialport();
         timer4.Interval = 10000; // testing on 10second interval
         timer4.Enabled = true;
    }
```

When i remove `Writetoserialport()` , the program runs forever.

Comment: What is preventing you from writing to the serial port in the button click event (where you start the timer) also? I feel like I must be missing something in your question.

Comment: @RufusL I am not sure if this is the one you mentioning, I have a SetTextCallback delegate that causes this same SetText() function to be called within the main thread instead of the second thread.

Comment: if it's form, why don't you use UI controls? set interval and just timer1.start() for do this.

Comment: @Arphile basically, inside my button, i should just include serialport1.write and timer1.start() thats all?

Comment: if you wish to start after press the button, you can add timer1.start() on button clicked event. if process finished, you just need to call timer1.stop().

Comment: @Arphile I have added some coding i tried is it correct? It doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Call `TimedEvent` directly for the first run:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(10*1000); 
    Timer1.Elapsed += TimedEvent;
    TimedEvent();
}
```

But for something that happens as rare as hourly, a Windows Service might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try but what you mentioned, the windoes service, what is that? How do i implement it?

Comment: I tried the code you gave, it states that "No overload for method 'TimedEvent' takes 0 arguments".

Answer (score 0):

This will work but will probably crash when you close the program sometimes because System.Timers.Timer triggers the TimedEvent on a ThreadPool thread. What will probably happen sometimes is when your program is closed, the SerialPort object will be disposed, but since the Timer is still executing on on another thread it will trigger the TimedEvent and try and write to the serialPort but it will crash the program because it will have been disposed.

You should look at System.Windows.Forms.Timer which is meant for using with GUI threads like this.

```
// INSTEAD, TRY THIS.
```

// It's really late here forgot to change some code after copy pasting from 
        above, should be good now.

```
    static System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(60*60*1000);
             timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
             timer1.Enabled = true;
             WriteToSerialPort(); // Call method directly for writing to port.
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             WriteToSerialPort(); 
    }

    private void WriteToSerialPort()
    {
             serialPort1.Write("high"); // write to port
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why, when i did not put in `WriteToSerialPort();` inside my button_click, the timer works but once i place it in, it doesn't work.

Comment: This is probably working poorly because, here, timer1 is static but it is attached but the timer1.Tick event is attached to a instanced method. I am a little surprised it even compiled. It was late. Please see my second example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example that allows you to not have a dedicated method for writing to the serial port. I would want the dedicated method so the serial port could be written to outside of the timer tick event without having to write the serial port code more than once. The code below needs to be in try...catch blocks. Note: System.Windows.Forms.Timer here.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SerialPortSample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Timer timer1 = new Timer { Interval = 1000, Enabled = false }; // initialize timer, with a one second interval and disabled
        private Button startTimerButton = new Button { Name = "startTimerButton",Text = @"Toggle Timer", Size = new Size(130, 33), Location = new Point(0, 0) };

        // This is a place holder for the SerialPort control you probably have on your Form.
        //Remove this instance of serialPort1 and use the serialPort1 control from your form.
        private SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort(); 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // add button to Form
            this.Controls.Add(startTimerButton); // add button to form1
            startTimerButton.Click += StartTimerButton_Click;
            timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick; // attach timer tick event
        }

        private void StartTimerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled; // toggle timer.endabled, if false the Tick event will not be raised
                timer1.Interval = 1000; // set timer interval to 1000 so the next time it is enabled it triggers immediately.
        }

        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 60 * 60 * 1000; // set timer interval to 1 hour so it will not trigger for an hour 

            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
                serialPort1.Open(); // open serial port if not open

            serialPort1.Write("high"); // write to the serial port

            serialPort1.Close(); // close serial port
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering if it will be alright if i use `thread.sleep` to hold down the program for an hour.

Comment: Thread.Sleep would not be a good choice here, the timer method will essentially make the program wait for an hour without blocking the main thread. What is the programs purpose, why do you want it to sleep?

Comment: I think I see, you were asking if you could use Thread.Sleep instead of a Timer. That would not work without creating another thread which would still be a poor option. Using Thread.Sleep would require you to create another Thread, which would require additional testing and Thread.Sleep is not a good option anyway. The Timer here is a perfect example of it's intended use. Is there something about the above sample that is too difficult or that needs further clarification?